# Code Editing - returning to previous edits

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've seen references to the ability (in VS08) to jump back and forth between the various places that i've been editing. E.G. I use 'Go to Definition' to inspect a method - what's the keyboard shortcut to return to where I was?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl-- (Ctrl and the minus key) goes back to the place from where the latest navigation command (e.g. Go-to-definition) was launched.

Comment: Thanks Xavier... I never knew that one, tons more useful than ctrl +K, K.

Comment: Thankx - one would like to think Ctrl-+ would allow forward movement letting me jump back and forth thru the stack of nav commands. Not so?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-Shift-Tab takes you to the previous document. You can Go To Definition and then hit Ctrl-Shift-Tab to go back. (Also, Ctrl-Tab takes you to the next document.)

Comment: Ok...that steps thru open documents. I thought there was a way to move between recent edit points. For example...in the case of 'Go To Definition' - if the given definition was in the same document i wouldn't want 'previous document', i'd want 'previous place i edited'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the functionality you are wanting can be achieved with bookmarking.

So, before you go to a definition, you could bookmark your spot.

The keyboard shortcuts for bookmarks are as follows:

Set/Unset Bookmark (Ctrl +K, K) 
Next Bookmark (Ctrl +K, N)

A few other shortcuts can be found at this [blog](http://blog.robvolk.com/2009/01/visual-studio-2008-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

Answer (score 0):

To go back to the previous place I edited, I usually hit Ctrl-Z then Ctrl-Y (Undo, Redo).